# Can't access html id tag when dynamically printed with Rails

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails

I have the following code:

```
<% @domains.each do |domain| %>
  <div id="<%= domain %>_chart"></div>
<% end %>

<script>
  $.plot($("#domain1_chart"), ...);
  $.plot($("#domain2_chart"), ...);
  .
  .
</script>
```

It seems that when the Javascript is called the div's id hasn't been set yet, or something along those lines. I've tried using settimeout() to call the $.plot and that doesn't work either. It does however work when I remove <%= domain %> from the id.

Any thoughts on how I can get this to work with dynamic ids?

Comment: What does the actual HTML code look like?

Comment: What are `@domains`? Is it an array of strings like this: `['domain1', 'domain2', ...]` ?

Comment: It is a set. When I view source, I see:

<div id="domain1_chart"></div>
<div id="domain2_chart"></div>
etc.

Comment: Why the down vote? I'm new to dynamic programming and asking a question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution:

```
<% @domains.each_with_index do |domain, i| %>
  <div id="domain<%= i %>_chart"></div>
<% end %>
```

---

**Fix**

You'll want to do some things better:

```
<% @domains.each_with_index do |domain, id| %>
   <%= content_tag :div, id: "domain#{id}_chart", class: "chart" do %>
      ...
   <% end %>
<% end %>
```

--

You'll also want to consider your javascript:

```
#app/assets/javascripts/application.js
var charts = function() {
   $(".chart")....
});
$(document).on("page:load ready", charts);
```

Notice how I'm calling the chart *class*? This is because you should only use `id`s to *identify* specific elements on your page. If you're going to use the same functionality for a collection of elements, you'll be better calling the class rather than the id

Comment: He's right about using a class. Also he provided a `document.ready` that will work with turbolinks. If you have turbolinks enabled then my solution won't work.

Comment: Thanks bud - inspiring to have someone recommend my anwswer!

Comment: Ahh, I am dynamically supplying different data to each chart which was why I needed to initialize them with individual calls. The problem ended up being that the id had a dot in it (because of the domain) and therefore couldn't be referenced, which your solution fixed. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You aren't waiting for the DOM to be ready:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.plot($("#domain1_chart"), ...);
    $.plot($("#domain2_chart"), ...);
});
```

Comment: Well then you’ll have to show us some code that actually makes this problem reproducible …

Comment: This is not a Rails issue I'm sure because the ids will be set long before any JavaSCript runs. They're set server-side before the page is rendered.

Comment: Okay, it must be something else. I will look again.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably with the jQuery plugin not waiting until the page has loaded.

Run your code inside of the document-ready method.

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $.plot($("#domain1_chart"), ...);
    $.plot($("#domain2_chart"), ...);
  });
</script>
```